# Remove 'fileExtension' and add 'mimeMap' to my config file for the Azure server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, fonts

I have this snippet below and in order for my fonts to work when I publish to Azure, I have to include it. Why?

Is there a way to publish to Azure without have to include these lines and still have my fonts work?

```html
<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, these lines are for **improving performance**!

Even with the missing .WOFF2 entry, Chrome will eventually find a font that it knows about and can find on the server. After all it works without all the fuss.

A 404 request is still a server request and there's latency and some bandwidth (headers and response) involved with every 404 request. Additionally, 404's on a server are nasty because they don't cache. So unlike a successful resource request which eventually ends up in the cache and won't get requested again by a browser, a 404 will always be re-requested adding extra overhead to any request that has to load your font so you take that extra server round trip on every page load that loads this 404 resource even if it was previously requested.

So, it's always a good idea to hunt down 404 errors in applications especially for things that get fired on every page.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/25/FontAwesome-Fonts-and-Mime-Types-in-IIS-and-other-Web-Servers).